# My program can't run accountType as a variable

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int accountNumber;
    float minimumBalance, currentBalance;
    char accountType;

    const float SAVINGS_SERVICE_CHARGE = 10.00;
    const float CHECKING_SERVICE_CHARGE = 25.00;
    const float SAVINGS_INTEREST_RATE = 0.04;
    const float CHECKING_LOW_INTEREST_RATE = 0.03;
    const float CHECKING_AVERAGE_INTEREST_RATE = 0.05;

    cout <<"Please the details of your account"<< endl;
    cin >> accountNumber,accountType,minimumBalance,currentBalance;

    switch (accountType){

        case 's':
        case 'S':
            cout <<"Account number"<<accountNumber<<endl;
            cout <<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);
            cout <<"Account type:Savings"<<endl;
            cout <<"Minimum Balance: $"<<minimumBalance << endl;
            cout <<"Current Balance: $"<<currentBalance << endl;

            if (currentBalance < minimumBalance) {
                cout <<"Service Fee:$"<<SAVINGS_SERVICE_CHARGE<<endl;}

            else {
                cout <<"Interest Earned:$"<<currentBalance * SAVINGS_INTEREST_RATE    << "at" << SAVINGS_INTEREST_RATE*100<<"p%.a"<<endl;
            }
            break;

        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            cout <<"Account number"<<accountNumber<<endl;
            cout <<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);
            cout <<"Account type:Checking"<<endl;
            cout <<"Minimum Balance:$"<<minimumBalance<<endl;
            cout <<"Current Balance:$"<<currentBalance<<endl;

            if (currentBalance < minimumBalance) {
                cout <<"Service fee:$"<<CHECKING_SERVICE_CHARGE<<endl;}
            else if (currentBalance <= (minimumBalance+5000.00)){
                cout <<"Interest Earned:$"<<currentBalance * CHECKING_LOW_INTEREST_RATE <<"at"<<CHECKING_LOW_INTEREST_RATE*100 <<"%p.a"<<endl;
            }else {
                cout <<"Interest Earned:$"<<currentBalance *      CHECKING_AVERAGE_INTEREST_RATE<< "at"<< CHECKING_AVERAGE_INTEREST_RATE*100     <<"%p.a"<<endl;
            }
            break;
        default:
            cout <<"ERROR"<<endl;
            return 1;
            break;
    }

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My program can't read accountType as a variable. What should I do to make it run as a variable? Please tell me what to do step by step and what is my error and what to do to make it work.

Comment: `cin >> accountNumber,accountType,minimumBalance,currentBalance;` this does not do what you think it does. Youre supposed to chain operator >>, not use , (in fact , practically never does what newcomers expect it to)

Comment: What should i do? :/

Comment: THANKS FOR THE HELP I GOT IT. :)

Comment: Would you please post the solution so others can benefit from it?

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments already tell

```
cin >> accountNumber,accountType,minimumBalance,currentBalance;
```

is wrong, since you are taking one input for multiple variables, if you want it right, you should use the >> operator every variable.

```
cin >> accountNumber >> accountType >> minimumBalance >> currentBalance;
```

which equals the same as

```
cin >> accountNumber;
cin >> acccountType;
...
```

In my opinion i would also not use global namespace usings, but that's for sure an other topic.